# iPhone -Passing an object from a view controller to tabbed view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

At the moment I plan on having a spash/login screen on my iphone app and then once a connection is made to the server a tabbed view will be shown. I have linked a button up to simulate the login. And that does [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toMainScreen" sender:self];

If I make an pointer to a object (connection control for TCP/UDP + threads) in the first view controller how would I pass it to the tabs or tab controller so that they have the ability to send / receive etc?

(maybe I pass the object to the tabbed view controller and then the tabs can get to it from there?) - Not sure how to do it though. I would assume that I would need to make a class for the tabbed view controller.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you will need to subclass your tab bar controller and have a property in there that will be a pointer to your first view controller. So your tabbar controller's .h file will look like this:

```
@interface MyTabBarController : UITabBarController

@property (nonatomic, weak) FirstViewController *firstViewController;

@end
```

when your first view controller is loaded you should set this property to it.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks. I think your answer is the way that I was going to do it. Then using the prepareForSegue method to set that pointer to firstViewController.

Comment: I read that it is not good practice to have ViewControllers have reference/pointers to other ViewControllers and its best to have a singleton in the AppDelegate.